# Unbind Facebook from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

My application uses authentication through Facebook. When I log in the very first time - it asks username and password, it's OK. But when I come out of the application, delete it, delete the app from my account settings Facebook then install app again and log in through facebook - it already knows my login and password, and do not asks me to enter new data. How do I completely decoupled the application Facebook account? On a device is NOT installed Facebook app and in the device settings is NOT tied Facebook account.

Comment: Can you please share your code so we can see how you are doing the facebook log in and storing the username and password?

Comment: I used Facebook SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2?locale=ru_RU)

Comment: It will be because somewhere in the code the username and password are being stored in the `Keychain` or in `NSUserDefaults` and they aren't being cleared down afterwards.

Comment: I delete app and install again and don't use NSUserDefaults. Did NSUserDefaults is not cleared after you uninstall an application  ?

Comment: No they don't clear automatically you have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

just use for logout

```
-(void)logoutButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
```

and after all logout from -> Settings -->Facebook
and also logout from if facebook application installed..
and also logout from if it login from browser...
Absolutely at will ask for login ....
I hope this will help you..

Comment: Thanks, but I already used this code and app still knows my login and password.

Comment: You logged out it from your browser...?

Comment: you can also use these two statement in logout action
[FBSession.activeSession close];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];

Refer to these link..
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/class/FBSession/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/class/FBSession/#close